# Spring MVC Application runs on "incorrect" URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am working with some other people on a Spring MVC web application. If i run the application it uses the URL http://localhost:8080/mywebapp but if others run it, the application uses the URL http://localhost:8080/x.

Is there any configuration i could do to let the application run on a specific URL?

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />

        <context:component-scan base-package="z.y.x.mywebapp" />

        <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

        <import resource="hibernate-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

        <servlet>
                <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

                <servlet-mapping>
                <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
                <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <listener>
                <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>
</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

        <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>
</beans>
```

I am fairly new to this, if there are any Information missing please let me know.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its defined in server.xml within tomcat :

```
<Context docBase="yourSource" path="/yourPath" ...
```

If using war files, the name of the war file itself (you can just right click an rename), which if using maven is set in the pom :

`<build><finalname>blahblah`

Comment: I guess the problem is, that we haven't defined it anywhere. Neither in the server.xml nor in the pom. thx i will try it.